# Wordwrap problem in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am having a textview with multi line text. In some places textview is having webpage address like google.com yahoo.com etc.., Now because of multi line, wordwrap functionality is splitting **google.** in one line and **com** in other line, same is happening for **yahoo.** in one line and **com** in other line.

Is there any way to specify that some words in the string should not be splitted in android?

-RR..

Answer (score 1):

you have to load your string as Html content. For Example, think that this your String

```
Android is a software stack for mobile devices that includes an operating system, middleware and key applications. <a>http://www.google.co.in</a> The Android SDK provides the tools and APIs necessary to begin developing applications on the Android platform using the Java programming language.
```

you have to put `<a>` tag to doesnot affect the wordwrap.

you have to load your String like this: `textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(content_String));`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But if i use <a></a> then that string will be hyper linked. But i dont want this behaviour. The strings should not be hyperlinked and is there any way to tell android not to split some words during wrapping.